Noscript extension can't be disabled
All browsers can remove if not disable extensions. Why can't I at least disable noscript extension?

That's how the Tor browser is built. It's not just a regular browser but it's a tweaked combo to keep you as private as possible. So - quite a lot of tweaks and trade-offs have been made to achieve that. Some components are hardcoded for good - like the one you're mentioning - it's like a kernel module that is statically compiled-in, not as a separate one. The reason is to make unloading the essential parts impossible - so no malware can do so in order to deanonymize you
